# Replacing values in high-frequency data

Tags: r, replace, subset

I've got high frequency data about durations. I've found out that I've got some faulty entries that I cannot discard that have 1800*random number added to them. Now I was stupid enough to try:

```
for(i in 1:21863924) {while(rr[i]>=1800){rr[i]=rr[i]-1800}}
```

Which obviously didn't work even though I left it overnight. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way for this,since subsetting the dataset to exclude the faulty entries works in matter of seconds ?

Comment: I would create a logical index first `i1 <- rr >= 1800` and then use that index to replace the values `rr[i1] <- rr[i1] - 1800`  Note that these are vectorized and don't have to loop over each element

Comment: If it needs to e recursive, create that as a function and call it recursively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a vectorized way.  Create a logical `vector`

```
i1 <- rr >= 1800
```

Use that vector to replace the values while assigning the values to the original vector

```
rr[i1] <- rr[i1] - 1800
```

---

A recursive function would be

```
f1 <- function(x, val) {
      i1 <- x >= val
       x[i1] <- x[i1] - val
      if(sum(x >= val) > 0) f1(x, val)
   }
out <- f1(rr, val = 1800)
sum(out >= 1800)
#[1] 0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
rr <- sample(20000, 100)
```